# Unable to upload new product to shopify using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, shopify-api

I have tried a lot but I am still unable to post product to shopify store using Apps Script. I am using the correct key and password but its not working. I am not getting any errors but I get a list of all products in my store in the response.

Here is my code

```
var storeName = ""
var key = ""
var secret = ""
uRL = "https://"+storeName+".myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-10/products.json"
params = {
    "headers": {
    "method":"POST",
    "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(key+":"+secret),
    "contentType":"application/json",
    "charset":"utf-8"
    },
    "products": {
        "product": {
            "body_html":"",
            "product_type": "JEWELLERY - Bracelets",
            "published_scope": "global",
            "title":"Burton Custom Freestyle 151",
            "vendor":storeName,
            "status":"active",
            "published":true,
            "tags":"",
            "price":"100"
        }
    },
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true
}
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(uRL, params);
var r = JSON.parse(response)
console.info(r)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```js
params = {
    "headers": {
    "method":"POST",
    "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(key+":"+secret),
    "contentType":"application/json",
    "charset":"utf-8"
    },
    "products": {
        "product": {
            "body_html":"",
            "product_type": "JEWELLERY - Bracelets",
            "published_scope": "global",
            "title":"Burton Custom Freestyle 151",
            "vendor":storeName,
            "status":"active",
            "published":true,
            "tags":"",
            "price":"100"
        }
    },
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true
}
```

#### To:

```js
var params = {
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": { "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(key + ":" + secret) },
  "contentType": "application/json",
  "muteHttpExceptions": true,
  "payload": JSON.stringify({
    "products": {
      "product": {
        "body_html": "",
        "product_type": "JEWELLERY - Bracelets",
        "published_scope": "global",
        "title": "Burton Custom Freestyle 151",
        "vendor": storeName,
        "status": "active",
        "published": true,
        "tags": "",
        "price": "100"
      }
    }
  })
};
```

Or,

```js
var params = {
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": { "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(key + ":" + secret) },
  // "contentType": "application/json",
  "muteHttpExceptions": true,
  "payload": JSON.stringify({
    "products": {
      "product": {
        "body_html": "",
        "product_type": "JEWELLERY - Bracelets",
        "published_scope": "global",
        "title": "Burton Custom Freestyle 151",
        "vendor": storeName,
        "status": "active",
        "published": true,
        "tags": "",
        "price": "100"
      }
    }
  })
};
```

- From [the document of "Create a new product"](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-10/resources/product#%5Bpost%5D/admin/api/2021-10/products.json), I thought that `"contentType": "application/json"` might not be required to be used.

#### References:

- [Create a new product](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-10/resources/product#%5Bpost%5D/admin/api/2021-10/products.json)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Works now, thank you so much. 
Had to comment out "products"

Comment: @Osama Khan Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.